# Not Found page rendering for an entire page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Below in the App.js file ,   the routes component wraps part of the website , but i needed the NotFound component to be rendered for the whole page if a wrong url was entered , please advice on how this can be done in this case , i appreciate your feedback

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/tours" element={<Tours />} />
        <Route path="/music" element={<Music />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
      </Routes>
      <Testimonials />
      <Footer />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a layout route that renders the `Navbar`, `Testimonials`, `Footer`, ***and*** an `Outlet` for nested `Route` components to be rendered into. Render the `NotFound` component ***outside*** this layout route.

Read more about layout routes [here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes).

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const App Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render here
    <Testimonials />
    <Footer />
  </>
);
```

...

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/tours" element={<Tours />} />
          <Route path="/music" element={<Music />} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

If the `NotFound` component doesn't need the base CSS styling or `Box` container then move these into the `AppLayout` components as well.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is render a Route with a ***path = " * "***, and React Router will make sure to only render the element if none of the other Routes match.

For react-router ***version 6***

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />}></Route>
    <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Show url as 404** of not found page

*Redirect* component has been removed from the react-router *version 6*. For react-router-dom v6, simply replace *Redirect with ***Navigate****

```
<Route path="/404" element={<PageNotFound></PageNotFound>} />
<Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/404" />} />
```

Comment: thank you but this not what i meant , you can see in my question there are components which are not Wrapped with the Routes component , so these components will still be there even if i typed the wrong  address , i want the entire website to render the NotFound component only

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use a wildcard path `"*"` after all valid routes. In this way it will 1st try to match the current user's path with the path provided inside `<Route/>` and if the path matches the existing **route** it will render that **route's** component. And when it will not match with your existing path then it will render the `wildcard route` and inside the wildcard route, you can render the **404 Not Found** page. For example:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/tours" element={<Tours />} />
        <Route path="/music" element={<Music />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFoundComponent/>} />
      </Routes>
      <Testimonials />
      <Footer />
    </Box>
  );
};
```

***Note:** The `<Route path="*"/>` should be placed after all existing routes or else your react app will render a `404` page every time*

Comment: thank you but this not what i meant , you can see in my question there are components which are not Wrapped with the Routes component , so these components will still be there even if i typed the wrong  address , i want the entire website to render the NotFound component only